# Google Fit REST API move minutes

Tags: google-fit-api

I am trying to access google fit API to return my move minutes. I have tried aggregate and merged data sources
It also does not seem to work for the steps count, too

```
{
      "dataStreamId": "derived:com.google.active_minutes:com.google.android.gms:from_activity<-merge_activity_segments",
      "dataStreamName": "from_activity<-merge_activity_segments",
      "type": "derived",
      "dataType": {
        "name": "com.google.active_minutes",
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "duration",
            "format": "integer"
          }
        ]
      },
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.gms"
      },
      "dataQualityStandard": []
    },
    {
      "dataStreamId": "derived:com.google.active_minutes:com.google.android.gms:from_steps<-estimated_steps",
      "dataStreamName": "from_steps<-estimated_steps",
      "type": "derived",
      "dataType": {
        "name": "com.google.active_minutes",
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "duration",
            "format": "integer"
          }
        ]
      },
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.gms"
      },
      "dataQualityStandard": []
    },
    {
      "dataStreamId": "derived:com.google.active_minutes:com.google.android.gms:merge_active_minutes",
      "dataStreamName": "merge_active_minutes",
      "type": "derived",
      "dataType": {
        "name": "com.google.active_minutes",
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "duration",
            "format": "integer"
          }
        ]
      },
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.google.android.gms"
      },
      "dataQualityStandard": []
    },
```

None of these data sources return my move minutes as given in the google fit android app.